# DevicePolicyManager, lock screen and HTC Sense

Tags: android, lockscreen, htcsense, device-policy-manager

I've written an application which just locks the screen if is started, based on the [Device Administration Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).
So far so good, after I activate the device administration for the application I am able to lock the screen with the `DevicePolicyManager.lockNow()` method.
It works fine on the emulator as well as on an Asus Transformer, however on devices with HTC Sense it just sends the device to standby mode - if I switch it on again I don't get the pasword- or unlock-gesture prompt.

Has anybody experienced something like that and knows how to *really* lock the device rather than just sending it to standby?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a number of people have encountered this issue. The closest I've seen to an answer is here, but I can't guarantee it works:
[Android lockNow() fails on HTC Desire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074091/android-locknow-fails-on-htc-desire)

Semi-related issue here, just in case it provides any clue:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17083